# Upload app update only for one country

Tags: itunes

I want to upload update in App store that shoudl be visible only for one country and in the same time the previous old version to be visible in other countries. Is is possible or once I make changes in section Rights and Pricing the new update will be visible in the selected country and the old one will be erased from the other markets where is visible now?

Answer (score 1):

No, once you submit an update for an app, the previous binaries will be removed from the App Store. It is not possible to provide an update to only a specific region.